# what is the use of failIfNotExists parameter in sitecore pipeline run method

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2

I'm trying to get response from my custom sitecore pipeline of run method, below is my code

```
  Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run("customPipelineName", args, true);
```

the third parameter is failIFnotExists. Can anybody explain the use of this parameter and how to get response from puipeline when I abort pipeline in processor.
 below is declaration in Kernel DLL

```
 public static void Run(string pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, bool failIfNotExists);
```

after decompile I found below implemetation for run method. if failIfNotExist parameter use is only to run or not  the pipeline then why can't we do it while calling run method?

```
if (pipeline == null && !failIfNotExists)
        return;
      Assert.IsNotNull((object) pipeline, "Could not get pipeline: {0} (domain: {1})", new object[2]
      {
        (object) pipelineName,
        (object) pipelineDomain
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

The usage of this parameter is quite simple. Like the comment says: *If set to true the code will throw an exception if pipeline not found*. Taking into consideration that comment and bellow decompiled code:

```
public override void Run(string pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, string pipelineDomain, bool failIfNotExists)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(pipelineName, "pipelineName");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) pipelineDomain, "pipelineDomain");
    CorePipeline pipeline = this.GetPipeline(pipelineName, pipelineDomain);
    if (pipeline == null && !failIfNotExists)
        return;
    Assert.IsNotNull((object) pipeline, "Could not get pipeline: {0} (domain: {1})", new object[2]
    {
        (object) pipelineName,
        (object) pipelineDomain
    });
    pipeline.Run(args);
}
```

you can see that it just about throwing an exception when the pipeline is not found or not. If you are not sure that the pipeline exists and can see this param to true and use try/catch statement in your code to know if the pipeline was run or it doesn't exist. It has nothing to do with the results of the pipeline when it gets aborted.

Regarding the pipeline results. You are passing args to the pipeline:

```
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run("customPipelineName", args, true);
```

Those can be your custom one or standard Sitecore ones. Everything what pipeline will do will be (should be) reflected in those args. If this is your custom pipeline and custom args than, put additional properties to those arguments and full fill them in the pipeline processors so even if one of the processors will abort pipeline it will be reflected in the args.